# VSCode Makefile Tools argv[1] has unexpected extra parameters

Tags: makefile, vscode-extensions

When running a binary through makefile tools, the `argv[1]` parameter contains extra characters, such as `getting-started.ini SHELL=... SESSION_MANAGER=...`, instead of just the expected `getting-started.ini`. Manually running the binary with entered arguments works correctly. Is it possible that the makefile tools are adding extra characters to the arguments?

Here is the settings.json for the makefile tools

```
{
    "makefile.configurations": [
        {
            "name": "default",
            "makeArgs": [
            ],
            
        }
    ],
    "makefile.makefilePath": "",
    "makefile.launchConfigurations": [
        {
            "cwd": "path",
            "binaryPath": "filepath",
            "binaryArgs": [
                "getting-started.ini"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": true
        },
        {
            "cwd": "path",
            "binaryPath": "filepath",
            "binaryArgs": [
                "getting-started.ini"
            ]
        },
    ],
    "makefile.makePath": "make"
}
```